# Algorithm for Spacing CSS Menu Elements According to Screen Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algorithm

I am making a main menu page for my personal portfolio. It keeps proper spacing when adjusting width, and I have a custom layout for mobile. However, adjusting the height makes the entire page look terrible.

I have tried all day to make the elements space correctly, but I just can't seem to come up with the correct algorithm:

Note: This fires on page refresh. The problem makes more sense when you see it on full screen, so the JSFiddle link might be better than running the code below.

```js
   //Instantiate window width and height
  var h = $(window).height();
  var w = $(window).width();

   //Calculate margins between each box
  var boxmargin = String(55) + "px";
  $(".bmenu").children('li').children('a').children('p').css("margin-bottom", boxmargin);
  $("#triangleoverlay").css("overflow", "hidden");

   //Calculate left positioning of container so left edge is hidden
   //var lefthide = String( (1/h)*10000 )+"%";
   //$(".bmenu").css("right", lefthide);

   //Calculate box endpoints (start with max, end with 0)
  var boxwidth1 = String((h / 2.9594202898550726) / (1019 / h));
  $(".bmenu").children('li:first-child').children('a').children('p').css("padding-left", boxwidth1 + "px");
  var boxwidth2 = String(Number(boxwidth1) * 1.2028985507246377);
  $(".bmenu").children('li:nth-child(2)').children('a').children('p').css("padding-left", boxwidth2 + "px");
  var boxwidth3 = String(Number(boxwidth2) * 1.2771084337349397);
  $(".bmenu").children('li:nth-child(3)').children('a').children('p').css("padding-left", boxwidth3 + "px");
  var boxwidth4 = String(Number(boxwidth3) * 1.179245283018868);
  $(".bmenu").children('li:nth-child(4)').children('a').children('p').css("padding-left", boxwidth4 + "px");
```

```css
#triangleoverlay {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
#logo {
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#title {
  margin-top: 320px !important;
  margin-left: 45%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
}
.bmenu li a p {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  background: rgba(27, 43, 64, 0.7);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.bmenu:hover li a p {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ffffff;
  color: transparent;
  background: rgba(27, 43, 64, 0.2);
}
.bmenu li a:hover p {
  background: rgba(27, 43, 64, 1.0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader-section"></div>
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>

<div id='main'>
  <div id='triangle'>
    <svg class="slider-post-slanting" viewBox="0 0 1620 1620" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice" style="position:absolute; bottom: 0px;">
      <polygon opacity="0.7" fill="#2F4C6F" points="1600,1620 0,1620 0,0 500,0 "></polygon>
    </svg>
    <div id="triangleoverlay" style="position:absolute; height:100%">
      <img id="logo" height="100px" src="./images/logoinverted.png" />
      <ul class="bmenu" style="top:25%; right:7%; position:relative; list-style-type:none;">
        <li>
          <a href="about.html">
            <p>About Me</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="portfolio.html">
            <p>Portfolio</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="resume.html">
            <p>Resume</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>Contact</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="./images/titlenosub.png" id="title">
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Incoming:
http://jsfiddle.net/bq72ukc8/1/

Comment: not sure what you mean by ``to make the elements space correctly``. What is the desired effect here? Can you include some screenshots or something?

Comment: You should look into the vw/vh units. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: @Jeff: http://imgur.com/7M6CnWQ,tKzK77A - The one that has a height of 1021px is the desired effect. I want to make it so that the boxes have the same layout. (i.e. the bottom margins and length of the rounded boxes dynamically adjust based on the window size so everything will fit)

Comment: @Will: Yeah, I've used vw/vh quite a bit but I'm not entirely sure how I would use them here.